# There does not exist a group $G$ such that $|G/Z(G)|=pq$ for $p,q$ prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p$ and $q$ primes, with $p<q$ and $pk \neq q-1 \ , \ \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Show that there does not exist group $G$ such that
$$\left|\frac{G}{Z(G)}\right|=pq,$$ where $Z(G)$ is the center of $G$.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: prove the basic

**Lemma:** For any group $\,G\,$ , the quotient $\,G/Z(G)\,$ cannot be cyclic non-trivial, or in other words: for any group, $\,G/Z(G)\,$ is cyclic iff $\,G\,$ is abelian, and in this case the quotient is the trivial group.

Now just show that under the given data, a group of order $\,pq\,$ *must* be cyclic...

Comment: continue please

Comment: What "continue" and where?

Comment: Why a group of order pq must be ciclic?

Comment: (1) How many Sylow $\,p-\,$subgroups it has? (2) Thus, what is $\,PQ\,$ , with $\,P,Q\,$ Sylow subgroups of order $\,p,q\,$ respectively? (3) Thus, $\,PQ\cong P\times Q\,$ ...