# Show that do not exist $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There does not exist a group $G$ such that $|G/Z(G)|=pq$ for $p,q$ prime.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214480/there-does-not-exist-a-group-g-such-that-g-zg-pq-for-p-q-prime)

Let $p$ and $q$ prime numbers, with $p<q$ and $p \nmid (q-1)$. Show that do not exist group $G$ where
$$\left\lvert\frac{G}{Z(G)}\right\rvert=pq.$$

Comment: Isn't this the same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214480/there-does-not-exist-a-group-g-such-that-g-zg-pq-for-p-q-prime which you asked yesterday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Fact: If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then G is abelian.

Comment: You asked the very same question and you also wrote the very same comment. The answer, as it is, is enough for you to develop a solution. If there's something you don't understand *then* ask.

Comment: @JarbasDantasSilva What's the center of an abelian group?

Comment: the group...????????????

Comment: @JarbasDantasSilva itself